# How to configure msys2 in codeblocks?

Tags: codeblocks, msys2, esp-idf

How to configure **codeblocks** compiler and debugger with **msys2** ?

I found an answer related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972968/how-can-use-mingw-w64-and-msys2-with-any-ide-like-eclipse-or-codeblocks#answer-53132738), but I don't find very usefull as I use windows 7, instead linux ;)

What I want to achive is integrating esp-idf embedded system in codeblocks.

Is this even possible ? Anyone ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install CodeBlocks 20.03 without the compiler (installer: codeblocks-20.03-setup.exe, about 37.5 Mb)
2. Download and install Msys2 by following the instructions on the [homepage](https://www.msys2.org/)
3. Install the mingw-w64 toolchain (open the Msys64 shell and run the command: `pacman -S git mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake make mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`)
4. Now you need to configure the compiler in CodeBlocks. 
   Go to `Settings -> Compiler...` 
   [image: Settings menu] 
   Click on `Toolchain executables` tab and browse for `mingw64` folder (without bin).
   Edit the executable file names as `gcc.exe`, `g++.exe` and `g++.exe` 
   Click Ok to confirm 
   [image: Compiler setting]
5. Go to `Settings -> Debugger...` and configure `gdb.exe` as default debugger (browse for the `gdb.exe` file into the bin directory) 
   [image: Debugger setting] 
   Now the GCC compiler and the GDB debugger are configured. 
   You can use `pacman` from the Msys2 shell, to download and install or uninstall a lot of packages. 
   I don't know `esp-idf` but it seems to me that this sdk is not distributed as a msys2 package.

Comment: [Good MSYS2 installation instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).