# Code::Blocks is failing to build and run my project (file chain issues??)

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, codeblocks, digital-downloads

This is my build (ctrl + f9) error:

> Project/Target: "Password Giver - Debug":
>
> The compiler's setup (GNU GCC Compiler) is invalid, so Code::Blocks cannot find/run the compiler.
>
> Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
>
> Do you have a compiler installed?
>
> Goto "Settings->Compiler...->Global compiler settings->GNU GCC Compiler->Toolchain executables" and fix the compiler's setup.
>
> Tried to run compiler executable 'C:\MinGW/bin/gcc.exe', but failed!
>
> Skipping...

Also, when I try to run it (ctrl + f10), it provides the exact same error (except it says Run Aborted... at the end instead of Skipping...).

Basically, I think I completely screwed up my train of files, and I have no idea where to put the project I have. Its files consist of 3 CPPs, the CBP, a DEPEND and a LAYOUT. Currently all six are in the 'bin' subdirectory of MinGW just like the Toolchain executables told me too.

I set the main compiler to GNU GCC, and the C and C++ are gcc.exe and g++.exe respectively. I don't know which files these are referring to, if any, so that's probably not good.   :D

There is definitely something I'm missing...Does somebody know how to deal with this error?

You know it's bad when the error generator starts using interrobangs.

Randomly, I checked for the existence of the C and C++ compilers by going to Settings --> Global Compiler Settings ---> Toolchain executables and clicking on the dot dot dot next to the gcc.exe and g++.exe.

Both produced this:

> [gcc.exe
> File not found.
> Check name and try again.]
>
> [image: error window]

My files seem to have entirely gotten lost, or maybe my compiler did. I have no idea where to put anything, and which ones even matter.

P.S. Is the compiler a file?? If so, where?

Comment: First thing to check is does `C:\MinGW/bin/gcc.exe` actually point to a file on your system? If not, I recommend following [the instructions linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/4581301) tio install a high-quality compiler  and supporting tools and [then follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453827/how-to-configure-msys2-in-codeblocks) to tell Code::blocks where the compiler is. If Code::Blocks has never worked, odds are good that you downloaded a IDE-only release of Code::Blocks. If it worked and then stopped... Who can say what got eaten or how.

Comment: *"Randomly, I checked for the existence of the C and C++ compilers by going to Settings --\> Global Compiler Settings ---\> Toolchain executables and [...]"* -- How is following the directions in the error message "random"?

Comment: *"Basically, I think I completely screwed up my train of files,"* -- Why would you think that? The error message mentions "The compiler's setup", "the toolchain path", "a compiler", "Settings->Compiler...", "compiler executable". Every line of the error message other than the first (identifying what it is doing) and the last (saying that it is giving up) mentions your compiler, so maybe you should conclude that the problem is likely with the compiler? Why blame something else?

Comment: *"Currently all six are in the 'bin' subdirectory of MinGW"* Uhh, no, it didn't tell you that. You should (almost) never modify your compiler installation in any way. Given those other errors, I'd reinstall the compiler just in case (and replace it with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) to get something more up-to-date).

Comment: Are you confused by the word "toolchain", perhaps? It refers to the compiler and a few other tools that are installed with.