Compiling C/C++ code on windows11 with vscode
I am trying to compile and run c++ programs with vscode on win11 but experiencing problems with compiling part.
It is my first time working with c++ on windows. I have followed  the installation tutorial from vscode website VS Code MinGW tutorial.   After that i have restarted my system to be sure and  staterted to recive this error.  The path is correct. I tried to run my code (which is a simple hello world and a std::cin to make sure program waits me to see it ) yet it resulted with a new error

So i have tried to use terminal to see if it is a VS code problem or pc problem.
After wrting this command no errors but no file generations also. so i have tried to check g++.exe and gdb.exe and everthing looks solid in this part.
So i have tired with wsl in same device and everything works as intended. Then i tried with code blocks ide (edit: which was not installed prior to this. When i stumbled upon this problem i have installed code blocks.). Where codes compile  for c/c++ and run but when i click exe from file explorer exe from c works but exe from c++ gives an unexpected error. i also compiled a very similiar c code and exe for c code works as inteded when clicked from file explorer but exe compiled from c++ code yields given erorr:

can be translated as : Application cannot started properly (0xc0000279). Click ok to end the application.
Again this is a simple hello world code that can be run from code block ide without problem.
Below is the code, again it is just to test compiler installation.
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World From C++" << std::endl;

    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
}


Unless you have a requirement to use GCC build chain. I suggest using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition as it needs almost no configuration.

We get so many questions like this here. And to be honest I think you should ask them on a visual studio code help forum. Also note "visual studio code" is NOT beginner friendly. On windows I recommend you use "visual studio community edition" you will find it is a much easier experience.

@RichardCritten Double check :)

Looks like you have some missing or incompatible DLLs in your compiler

run but when i click exe from file explorer exe from c works but exe from c++ gives an unexpected error. Probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell caused by having multiple incompatible versions of the MinGW runtime installed. My advice for that is to remove the very old version of MinGW that Code::Blocks installed and setup Code::Blocks to use the msys2 version. Also you could have MinGW runtime files in a folder of your OS PATH environment variable that is from other software and not even a compiler.

^ Which is solved by moving MSYS2 to be the first thing in PATH.

Note that 0xc0000279 means STATUS_IO_REPARSE_TAG_NOT_HANDLED (which is one I have never seen before). And since WSL was mentioned, I think there are maybe symlinks created inside WSL at play here, which apparently Windows itself doesn't handle correctly.

The OP would be much better off using MSVC Community Edition with or without the Intel ICX addon which actually compiles most code to run faster. MinGW on windows has various interesting quirks even if you know exactly what you are doing. gcc on Unix works OK although I have never been able to get it to beat Intel code generation.

@drescherjm it is first time i have installed mingw on device and i have installed  code blocks after i have stumbled upon this problem. I  am current not seeing any mingw related entries in my os paths

@AlanBirtles is there any method i can apply to solve missing dll part?

So when you installed Code::Blocks you didn't have it install its own version of MinGW? And then you did the manual setup to use the MinGW from msys2 in Code::Blocks described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453827/how-to-configure-msys2-in-codeblocks
